# How to send a QR code which I read to the rest service?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to create a android application and I need to read QR code and send it to the rest service. I have successfuly read the QR code - thanks to Zxing. Then I need to store it in a variable (how?) and send it to the rest service. Do I need to use decoder package of Zxing? Can you give me some insight? Here is my code's related parts:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
   intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

---

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
             // Handle successful scan
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_bill, null);

            TextView errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);
            EditText payment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
            String amount = payment.getText().toString();

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try{

               //I should call rest here.

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                errorText.setText("ERROR!");    
            }
        } 

 else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
```

Thank you...

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610862/how-to-capture-data-from-qr-scanner-using-zxing ?

Comment: yes it is realted my problem thanks.